# Delete / Destroy using a link and Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I could have sworn I had this working at one point but now I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it won't. I found [this great script](https://gist.github.com/roNn23/a86f31ecaf0c6e0a7d65) which inserts a hidden form next to a delete link and then submits the form with the necessary token. I posted a message on the git site but no response.

I've set it up exactly as it suggests and looking through the DOM I can see the form is there, inserted. I've done some alerts to make sure it sees the token correctly but every time I get:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46:
```

If I put an old standard Laravel delete form it works fine, I just can't seem to get this script to work like it should. No other javascript errors or issues that I can find.

Here's the script with the code at the top that I added to my page:

```
 <a href="posts/2" data-method="delete"> <---- We want to send an HTTP DELETE request

 - Or, request confirmation in the process -

 <a href="posts/2" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">

 Add this to your view:
<script>
    window.csrfToken = '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>';
 </script>
<script src="/js/deleteHandler.js"></script>
 */

(function() {

var laravel = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.registerEvents();
    },

    registerEvents: function() {
        $('body').on('click', 'a[data-method]', this.handleMethod);
    },

    handleMethod: function(e) {
        var link = $(this);
        var httpMethod = link.data('method').toUpperCase();
        var form;

        // If the data-method attribute is not PUT or DELETE,
        // then we don't know what to do. Just ignore.
        if ( $.inArray(httpMethod, ['PUT', 'DELETE']) === - 1 ) {
            return;
        }

        // Allow user to optionally provide data-confirm="Are you sure?"
        if ( link.data('confirm') ) {
            if ( ! laravel.verifyConfirm(link) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        form = laravel.createForm(link);
        form.submit();

        e.preventDefault();
    },

    verifyConfirm: function(link) {
        return confirm(link.data('confirm'));
    },

    createForm: function(link) {
        var form =
            $('<form>', {
                'method': 'POST',
                'action': link.attr('href')
            });

        var token =
            $('<input>', {
                'name': '_token',
                'type': 'hidden',
                'value': window.csrfToken
            });

        var hiddenInput =
            $('<input>', {
                'name': '_method',
                'type': 'hidden',
                'value': link.data('method')
            });

        return form.append(token, hiddenInput)
            .appendTo('body');
    }
};

laravel.initialize();

})();
```

Comment: How's your route set up? Perhaps this could be an alternative if you can't get the script working: http://barryvdh.nl/laravel/jquery/2015/04/11/unobtrusive-javascript-with-jquery-ujs-and-laravel/

Comment: Looks like that could work, installed with bower but I'm not using an application.js so setup without doesn't seem to be documented

Comment: I figured it out - just add the rails.js include then follow your included instructions for adding csrf-token and csrf-param meta tags. Good solution. While doing that I realized I had a duplicate js function that was conflicting with my newer deleteHandler. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could be of some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As haakym suggested, one solution is [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://barryvdh.nl/laravel/jquery/2015/04/11/unobtrusive-javascript-with-jquery-ujs-and-laravel/). While implementing that I realized I had an old version of a delete handler in another js file that was conflicting with my [deleteHandler](https://gist.github.com/roNn23/a86f31ecaf0c6e0a7d65).

As usual many ways to achieve the same solution. Thanks for the input haakym.